# Beautify settings for require destructuring

Tags: javascript, node.js, js-beautify

I'm using js-beautify to make my JavaScript sexy. However there are a few things which just aren't sexy.

This:

```
const { ExecutionTime, log } = require('application/lib/log');
```

Gets turned into this:

```
const {
    ExecutionTime,
    log
} = require('application/lib/log');
```

I would like requires to stay on one line! Anyone know how?

Comment: Jup, thats the reason I turned off beautify ...